# Is it possible to retrieve Non Working Days using Greenhopper api?

Tags: jira, greenhopper, jira-plugin

I've developed a Jira plugin (a post function) which is working fine.  What I'd like this plugin to be able to do it to retrieve the Non Working Days that have been been previously saved using the Greenhopper plugin in Jira.

Is there a Greenhopper API available for this type of requirement?  I've searched for an api but have had no luck.

The following link as far as I can tell is for developing plugins for GreenHopper.

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GHDEV/GreenHopper+Developer+Documentation

It's not really what I'm after as I'm more interested in using their api to query information.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let those interested know...

After some further searching I found the answer!  This is how I'm getting the number of non working days:

```
import com.pyxis.greenhopper.GreenHopper;

.
.

GreenHopper ghService = (GreenHopper) ComponentManager.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(GreenHopper.class);

Set set = ghService.getConfiguration(issue.getProjectObject()).getNonWorkingDays();
```

The set contains the non working days configured in the GreenHopper configuration screen in Jira.

Just what I was after.

I hope that helps somebody out there :-)